# How to see profile assigned to a user

Tags: oracle-11g, users

Let's say i have **created** a user as **'TEST_USER'**, and then i assigned a profile to it.

Now how can i see for **TEST_USER** which **profile** has been **assigned**?

I want some query that will check what profile a user is assigned with.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to find out the users and the profile assigned you can use the commands below.

```
DESC DBA_USERS;
```

This will show you all the fields name for which you want to query

```
SELECT USERNAME, PROFILE, ACCOUNT_STATUS FROM DBA_USERS;
```

And this command will show you the user name, profile and account status i.e. which profile is assigned to which user

Answer (score 3):

You can find this information in dba_users.profile view:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5081.htm